# Zephyr for Jira Importer (zfj-importer) Connection denied

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-zephyr

In my company we already use JIRA and plan to use Zephyr for JIRA for our Testmanagement.

In order to test the AddOn I created a JIRA-Cloud test-account.

Now I want to import some test-cases using the [zfj-importer](https://bitbucket.org/zfjdeveloper/zfj-importer/wiki/Home)

When trying to connect with the tool, I get this error message:
[image: Error message in zfj-importer]

I followed the steps in the Wiki, so I don't know why I get this error? Maybe somebody has had this before.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was trying to connect behind my company proxy.

Switching to a "normal" network worked for me.